How can I read a pickle file in HDFS?

I have developed a deep learning model using PyTorch, then I saved it as a pickle file.

Now, I am working on HDFS and I have a table named XX. I want to use my deep learning model to get a result from this table.

The problem is when I run my job, I can't read the pickle file. I tried several methods, unfortunately none of them worked.

I tried to put the file in a folder in my space in HDFS. Using the path, I did:


command = f'hdfs dfs -get {path}' 
os.system(command=command)

The get was successful, but then when I did:
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'model.pkl')
binary_data = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(file_path).select("content").collect()[0][0]
model = pickle.loads(binary_data)

I got: Path does not exist hdfs://xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxx/.../model.pkl
Thank you for your help !
I was expecting to read the model and put it in a variable named model, and then use the model like everyone does.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe get path from error and try it with command hdfs - maybe there is mistake in path
